# Where can I find historical price of altcoins?

Tags: altcoin, historical-trade-data

[Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/CRYPTOCHART) has some dataset of altcoins but the history is small and unfortunately prices are not updated.

[CoinMarketCap JSON API](http://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/) is great but I understand it provides the lastest update only.

I have found on Bitcoincharts a file named rippleUSD.csv.gz but I don't understand the structure. A convertion of the unixtime with in MS Excel (i.e. =A1/(60*60*24)+"1/1/1970") returns the following dates and time but it is not clear if the last column is price because movements in a single minute interval are huge.

Looking at the Market Overiew API I haven't found relative informations about CSV file structure. Sorry my status does not allow me to post more than 2 links

```
1362466270  5/3/13 6:51 AM  37.5    4.24384928
1362466300  5/3/13 6:51 AM  37.5    2.83321826
1362466300  5/3/13 6:51 AM  37.5    1.89147286
1362466330  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    1.26275819
1362466330  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    0.84302465
1362466340  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    0.56264942
1362466340  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    0.37568073
1362466350  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    0.25084183
1362466350  5/3/13 6:52 AM  37.5    0.16748696
1362466380  5/3/13 6:53 AM  37.5    0.1118625
1362466380  5/3/13 6:53 AM  37.5    0.07468005
1362466410  5/3/13 6:53 AM  37.5    0.04984277
1362466410  5/3/13 6:53 AM  37.5    0.03327999
1362466480  5/3/13 6:54 AM  37.5    0.02228444
1362466490  5/3/13 6:54 AM  37.5    0.01485818
1362466490  5/3/13 6:54 AM  37.49999999 0.00990671
1362466520  5/3/13 6:55 AM  37.5    0.00660531
1362466520  5/3/13 6:55 AM  37.5    0.0044041
1362466550  5/3/13 6:55 AM  37.49999999 0.00293643
1362466790  5/3/13 6:59 AM  37.5    0.02613439
1362466930  5/3/13 7:02 AM  37.5    0.00194289
1362466980  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.49999999 0.00130038
1362466980  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.5    0.00087034
1362466990  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.49999999 0.00058252
1362467000  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.5    0.00038988
1362467000  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.49999999 0.00026095
1362467030  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.49999999 0.00011689
1362467030  5/3/13 7:03 AM  37.5    0.00017465
1362489380  5/3/13 1:16 PM  40.5    0.00014684
1362576360  6/3/13 1:26 PM  45  3.63539587
1362577870  6/3/13 1:51 PM  44.99999999 4.06298514
1362578760  6/3/13 2:06 PM  44.99999999 1.55555555
1362578950  6/3/13 2:09 PM  45  0.74606342
1362604140  6/3/13 9:09 PM  45.4    4.24261608
1362617400  7/3/13 12:50 AM 44  3.99999999
```

Do you know if there is website where it is possible to download historical price of big cap crypto currencies such as Dogecoin, Bitshares, DarkCoin and Ripple ?

Thank you,

Comment: Is the site still active and has the latest data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I run alt19, which is a free site which offers historical trade data on a large number of altcoins in CSV format. We have data at 15 minute, 1 hour, and 1 day increments.

http://alt19.com

Comment: Thank you Nick, it looks good. I try to figure out how to import these data in R. From what I see there is for each altcoin a chart page that contain daily prices at 6:00 PM within its source code. For example : http://alt19.com/19R/chart_showing_btc.php?shw=1&label=LTC_BTC&source=cryptsy&period=1day

Comment: Here is a solution to download the data in R : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323724/how-to-import-data-table-of-a-google-chart-in-r

Comment: Site no longer seems to have the data to download. Or I'm an idiot and just can't find the download button...

Answer (score 3):

http://www.CryptoDataDownload.com is new - mainly aggregates data from 28+ exchanges and lets you download it in CSV format for free. there are over 500+ pairs and the timeframes are Daily, Hourly, or Minute. No registration required or gimmicks. Data sets updated daily

Comment: Great resource mate! If you are part of the project, please consider adding volume to the tick data

Answer (score 1):

http://www.worldcoinindex.com/ maybe? try to ask them at their BTT thread https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=384546.0 or maybe CoinMarketCap if asked privately will provide you with the enhanced API?